# Run for loop on 2 variables from dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to run for loop on 2 columns coming from a dataframe and return a dict. But when i use zip I am getting only a part of a string on which the loop is running.

```
import pandas as pd

def split(owner, cost):
    
    split_bill = {'ads': 0, 'qaweb': 0, 'ovt': 0, 'cs': 0, 'edu': 0, 'xms': 0, 'cc': 0}

    for owner_in, cost in zip(owner, cost):  --> #need to know what type of loop can work here
        split_bill[owner_in] += cost
        continue
    return split_bill


data = {
  "owner": ['ads', 'cs', 'edu'],
  "cost": [2.3, 4.30, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['metric'] = df.apply(lambda x: split(x.owner, {x.cost}), axis=1)
```

Exptected output

```
df['metric'] =

metric
{'ads': 2.3, 'qaweb': 0, 'ovt': 0, 'cs': 0, 'edu': 0, 'xms': 0, 'cc': 0}
{'ads': 2.3, 'qaweb': 0, 'ovt': 0, 'cs': 4.3, 'edu': 0, 'xms': 0, 'cc': 0}
{'ads': 2.3, 'qaweb': 0, 'ovt': 0, 'cs': 0, 'edu': 45, 'xms': 0, 'cc': 0}
```

in the `for loop owner_in` is only taking `a of ads` Which should be taking `ads instead of a`.

Can you help with what type of loop could work?

Comment: What are you trying to do. When you `zip()` on string you're getting individual characters. Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely what can I use then? so that it takes full string instead of individual character?

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is to zip some lists into list of tuple. The length of the final list is determined by the shortest list among those list.

In your example, `owner` is a string `ads`, `cost` is a set with one float value. In `zip(owner, cost)`, string is treated as a list with three values. So the length of final list is 1 determined by the shortest set which has only one float value.

I guess you may want to do `df.groupby('owner')['cost'].apply(sum)`.

Comment: no groupby won't work because I want to create a metric column of the type I showed you. Is there any for loop which can run on owner and cost together coming from dataframe?

Comment: @shreytyagi Maybe `for owner, cost in zip(df['owner'], df['cost'])`?

Comment: any other way? zip is not returning full string

Comment: @shreytyagi What does *not returning full string* mean?

Comment: Sorry I mean it is using ```a``` instead of ```ads``` when i pass owner to zip

Comment: @shreytyagi `owner` and `cost` in your `split` method are just a value. You needn't use `zip` at all.

Comment: @Ynjxsmh then how can i use loop on them?

Comment: @shreytyagi Why do you want to loop? There is no need for loop.

Comment: @shreytyagi Looking at your expected output. I think you may want to define `split_bill` dict outside the `split` function.